# Threads in EF core requests

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Can anyone point me to the details of how requests works for EF Core. For example we are using lazy loading and looping through 10 object in which we accessing some navigation property. According to docs it'll result to 10 db requests.
 How does this happens under the hood? Is there dedicated threads for each db request? Or it send request to driver and then relies on it? Or there is some special io threads for this?
Thanks anyone for sharing !

Answer (score 0):

> How does this happens under the hood?

When you access a property it will trigger a load of the related elements. NOTHING using a separate thread here, this is a synchronous operation for you.

> Is there dedicated threads for each db request?

They happen on the one thread that accesses the property. CAREFUL: Using 10 threads to access the properties of 10 objects in parallel IS NOT SUPPORTED. EfCore does NOT support multi threading as per documentation.

It is quite simple. No threading involved at all.